# Return first truthy value in disjunction with the same function

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
def find_animal
  animal_type = AnimalKind.find_by(conditions) ||
                Animal.find_by(conditions) ||
                Breed.find_by(conditions)
end
```

I would like to refactor it to something like:

```
def find_animal
  animals = [AnimalKind, Animal, Breed]
  animal_type = animals.first_not_nil { |m| m.find_by(conditions) } 
end
```

Any idea on how to implement `first_not_nil` method?

Answer (score 7):

[`Enumerable#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) will short-circuit and return the first object for which the block returns a truthy value. But it doesn't return the result of the value (as pointed out by Oleskar Verhun). So, you could store the result in a variable outside of the loop, like this:

```
animal = nil
[AnimalKind, Animal, Breed].detect { |klass| 
  animal = klass.find_by(conditions) 
}

animal # will be nil or the first animal found by the supplied conditions
```

Comment: It's hard to improve on this. I would only suggest a minuscule stylistic change, and that is to use `find` rather than `detect`, as I think it reads better with `find_by`.

Comment: This will find the class, but what's asked in the question is to find the record of particular model class, so that means you also need to add `find_by(conditions)` in the end.

Comment: Thanks @OleksandrVerhun. Fixed up the answer.

Comment: how to generate a oneline function on array? The `first_or_nil` of the question